# Django: Heroku Failing to launch, at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"

Tags: django, git, heroku

Trying to Launch an application on Heroku and for the past few weeks I just cannot seem to get past this error. I setup my repo correctly and everything pushed to Heroku via git then when I open my site via the link given to me, I see the application failure error message. I view my logs but cannot seem to decipher where the error is coming from or how to begin to debug. If anyone can help that would be amazing! Thank you!

My log message below:

```
2015-02-02T04:01:38.814574+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn indie_app.wsgi`
2015-02-02T04:01:39.881951+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-02-02T04:01:39.881989+00:00 app[web.1]:     sys.exit(run())
2015-02-02T04:01:39.882016+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run
2015-02-02T04:01:39.881966+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
2015-02-02T04:01:39.882149+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 71, in run
2015-02-02T04:01:39.882183+00:00 app[web.1]:     Arbiter(self).run()
2015-02-02T04:01:39.882250+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.manage_workers()
2015-02-02T04:01:39.882055+00:00 app[web.1]:     WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2015-02-02T04:01:39.882129+00:00 app[web.1]:     super(Application, self).run()
2015-02-02T04:01:39.882077+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 185, in run
2015-02-02T04:01:39.882210+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 169, in run
2015-02-02T04:01:39.882270+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 477, in manage_workers
2015-02-02T04:01:39.882356+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.spawn_workers()
2015-02-02T04:01:39.882376+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 542, in spawn_workers
2015-02-02T04:01:39.882473+00:00 app[web.1]:     time.sleep(0.1 * random.random())
2015-02-02T04:01:39.882563+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 459, in reap_workers
2015-02-02T04:01:39.882493+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in handle_chld
2015-02-02T04:01:39.882652+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2015-02-02T04:01:39.882741+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2015-02-02T04:01:39.882542+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.reap_workers()
2015-02-02T04:01:40.654279+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-02-02T04:01:40.673618+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-02-02T04:01:40.674364+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-02-02T04:01:50.369085+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn indie_app.wsgi`
2015-02-02T04:01:52.540605+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 185, in run
2015-02-02T04:01:52.540682+00:00 app[web.1]:     super(Application, self).run()
2015-02-02T04:01:52.540719+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 71, in run
2015-02-02T04:01:52.540770+00:00 app[web.1]:     Arbiter(self).run()
2015-02-02T04:01:52.540800+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 169, in run
2015-02-02T04:01:52.540859+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.manage_workers()
2015-02-02T04:01:52.540886+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 477, in manage_workers
2015-02-02T04:01:52.541011+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.spawn_workers()
2015-02-02T04:01:52.541038+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 542, in spawn_workers
2015-02-02T04:01:52.541156+00:00 app[web.1]:     time.sleep(0.1 * random.random())
2015-02-02T04:01:52.541181+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in handle_chld
2015-02-02T04:01:52.541248+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.reap_workers()
2015-02-02T04:01:52.541276+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 459, in reap_workers
2015-02-02T04:01:52.541383+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2015-02-02T04:01:52.541508+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2015-02-02T04:01:52.540589+00:00 app[web.1]:     WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2015-02-02T04:01:52.540379+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
2015-02-02T04:01:52.540315+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-02-02T04:01:52.540502+00:00 app[web.1]:     sys.exit(run())
2015-02-02T04:01:52.540530+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run
2015-02-02T04:01:53.479723+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-02-02T04:01:53.497538+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-02-02T04:01:53.908609+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by egbe@usc.edu
2015-02-02T04:02:04.383428+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=salty-refuge-1024.herokuapp.com request_id=1abfe0da-fbd2-45f8-bd2f-52b5423acf6b fwd="24.228.44.221" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-02-02T04:02:04.774497+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=salty-refuge-1024.herokuapp.com request_id=bf481dcb-e6d2-4620-b19c-982b5bd3d531 fwd="24.228.44.221" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-02-02T04:02:04.689179+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=salty-refuge-1024.herokuapp.com request_id=46733f84-e2b4-4b0a-9733-e70cbc0f2d95 fwd="24.228.44.221" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: @Raja indie_app is the name of my project where my settings.py is located

Comment: For me, I have installed extra dependencies, but haven't added those in `requirements.txt` lol silly me

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks like heroku can't start the webserver and so changed the app status to crashed. Everytime when I get this error code the `Procfile` was misconfigured or had errors.

Answer (score 52):

The same error occurs when the `gunicorn` package is not installed (in your `virtualenv`). Here is a similar traceback as of October 2016:

```
2016-10-21T08:35:56.041002+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 
desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mygreatapp.herokuapp.com 
request_id=blablabla fwd="188.73.193.22" dyno= connect= service= 
status=503 bytes=
```

I was so impatient and during the conversion of my local app to a Heroku one (which includes the creation of `Procfile`, `runtime.txt`, `.gitignore` files, installation of `dj-database-url`, `whitenoise`) I forgot to install the most important package (`pip install gunicorn`)!!!

Doing so, `H10 error` vanished!

cheers!

Comment: And Heroku tutorial gracefully ignored to mentioned this.

Comment: I have also install gunicorn, Also complete setting ProcFile they why its getting

Comment: So that you don't go looking at how to install it, `pip install gunicorn`.

Answer (score 7):

i was also getting similiar problem
then changed Procfile and it worked
previously

```
web: gunicorn django_project.wsgi
```

edited

```
web: gunicorn django_project.wsgi:application --log-file - --log-level debug
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 4):

For users who are deploying the Django app via heroku for the first time, make sure you give the correct app name in the Procfile. I made this mistake during my first deployment.

```py
web: gunicorn appname.wsgi:application --log-file - --log-level debug
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
manage.py migrate
```

Here "appname" is name of my project where settings.py file is present.

Answer (score 0):

i got this error due to new whitenoise configuration. i changed it and it works now.

Your WhiteNoise configuration is incompatible with WhiteNoise v4.0
2020-08-22T08:14:04.757895+00:00 app[web.1]: This can be fixed by following the upgrade instructions at:
2020-08-22T08:14:04.757895+00:00 app[web.1]:
check out this site for new configuration => http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/changelog.html#v4-0

Answer (score 0):

This error mostly caused by the misconfiguration of `Procfile`.

I had the same problem and which was an extra space between `web` and `:` in my `Procfile`.
After fixing that the app worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
web: gunicorn djang_project_name.wsgi:application --log-file - --log-level debug
heroku ps:scale web=1
python manage.py migrate
```

This solved my problem.

I previously did the part of `python manage.py collectstatic`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this error the first time I was deploying on heroku:
Previously my Procfile was:

```
web: gunicorn movierater.wsgi --log-file-
```

Edited that to:

```
web: gunicorn movierater.wsgi --log-file -
```

The space after file was missing. After that run,
`git add .`
`git commit -m "message"`
`git push heroku main --force`

Answer (score -1):

**Add gunicorn in requirement.txt done!!**
I wasted hour with this error.

make sure you have **Procfile**:

```
web: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT project_name:app
```

remember to ip should be `0.0.0.0`

and add requirement file with `gunicorn`.

Comment: what's `hello:app`?

Comment: @Nitwit if you are referring to some guides or docs then for better understanding and staying on the same page then generally refer to their example app as hello. You can replace hello with your app name.