# Can't deploy django app with django-allauth to heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

When I want to deploy my Django app to heroku with `git push heroku master`, I got an error like this:

```
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     No 'Pipfile.lock' found! We recommend you commit this into your repository.
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.7
remote: -----> Installing dependencies with Pipenv 2018.5.18…
remote:        Installing dependencies from Pipfile…
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
remote:            django.setup()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
remote:            apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
remote:            app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
remote:            module = import_module(entry)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
remote:            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
remote:        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allauth'
remote: 
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote: 
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote: 
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote: 
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to *.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/*.git
```

but I have django-allauth in my requirements.txt

```
certifi==2018.11.29
chardet==3.0.4
defusedxml==0.5.0
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.1.4
django-allauth==0.38.0
django-heroku==0.3.1
idna==2.8
oauthlib==2.1.0
pkg-resources==0.0.0
psycopg2==2.7.6.1
python3-openid==3.1.0
pytz==2018.7
requests==2.21.0
requests-oauthlib==1.0.0
urllib3==1.24.1
whitenoise==4.1.2
```

and this is the order of INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py if it could help:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',

    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',

    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'accounts',
]
```

I should mention that if I disable the collect static, I can push to heroku, but my app faced with the same error when I check the logs.

my template was based on [heroku/heroku-django-template](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-django-template).

Comment: please add your Pipfile there. Because it seems that Heroku installs dependencies from Pipfile but not from requirements.txt.

Comment: did you mean I should install allauth with sth like 'pipenv install django-allauth'? @SergeyPugach

Comment: I can't understand what you use, requirements.txt or Pipenv? If you want to use requirements you need to delete Pipfile, if you want to use Pipenv delete requirements.txt and install all packages with `pipenv install ...` So could you copy there you Pipenv file in order to check if `django-allauth` is there?

Comment: I delete the Pipfile and the problem was solved, but I faced with new error that says 'at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"' but I don't think that is related to this topic. by the way, thanks for your help my dear friend :)

Comment: If you want write down your answer bellow for other people ...

Comment: I've posted answer. Please set it as solution if it helped. About your second issue, it seems that you doesn't have `favicon.ico` file in your project.  Good luck.

Comment: no the file was there, maybe that's because of sth with withenoise and static files, I should search for it ...

Comment: for solving the second problem based on [https://stackoverflow.com/a/40172326/4417806], I should add gunicorn to req.txt :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you try to use both `Pipenv` and `requirements.txt`. Delete `Pipfile` if you want to use `requirements.txt` and Heroku will install dependencies from that file.