# Django server crashes once deployed

Tags: python, django, heroku

The server builds successfully. Once Its built, and I go to view it, i gives me an application error. Still new to deploying via heroku and django, so if this is obvious please be helpful!
It keeps saying module not found with 'locallibrary', where I do not have a module named local library.

Here is the log

```
2020-09-29T02:20:16.043818+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-09-29T02:20:16.043818+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-09-29T02:20:16.043818+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-09-29T02:20:16.043819+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-09-29T02:20:16.043822+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-09-29T02:20:16.043823+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-09-29T02:20:16.043823+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-09-29T02:20:16.043824+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-09-29T02:20:16.043824+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-09-29T02:20:16.043824+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-09-29T02:20:16.043825+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-09-29T02:20:16.043825+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-09-29T02:20:16.043826+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-09-29T02:20:16.043826+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2020-09-29T02:20:16.043826+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-09-29T02:20:16.043827+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-09-29T02:20:16.043827+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-09-29T02:20:16.043828+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-09-29T02:20:16.043828+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-09-29T02:20:16.043828+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-09-29T02:20:16.043829+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-09-29T02:20:16.043829+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-09-29T02:20:16.043882+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'locallibrary'
2020-09-29T02:20:16.044104+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-09-29 02:20:16 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2020-09-29T02:20:16.086171+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-09-29T02:20:16.086182+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 202, in run
2020-09-29T02:20:16.086549+00:00 app[web.1]: self.manage_workers()
2020-09-29T02:20:16.086550+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 545, in manage_workers
2020-09-29T02:20:16.086847+00:00 app[web.1]: self.spawn_workers()
2020-09-29T02:20:16.086852+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 617, in spawn_workers
2020-09-29T02:20:16.087198+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1 * random.random())
2020-09-29T02:20:16.087203+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2020-09-29T02:20:16.087422+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2020-09-29T02:20:16.087427+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2020-09-29T02:20:16.087705+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2020-09-29T02:20:16.087805+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2020-09-29T02:20:16.087897+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-09-29T02:20:16.087897+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2020-09-29T02:20:16.087898+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-09-29T02:20:16.087934+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-09-29T02:20:16.087973+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
2020-09-29T02:20:16.088173+00:00 app[web.1]: sys.exit(run())
2020-09-29T02:20:16.088212+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in run
2020-09-29T02:20:16.088429+00:00 app[web.1]: WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2020-09-29T02:20:16.088469+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 228, in run
2020-09-29T02:20:16.088779+00:00 app[web.1]: super().run()
2020-09-29T02:20:16.088780+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
2020-09-29T02:20:16.088921+00:00 app[web.1]: Arbiter(self).run()
2020-09-29T02:20:16.088958+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 229, in run
2020-09-29T02:20:16.089177+00:00 app[web.1]: self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
2020-09-29T02:20:16.089217+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt
2020-09-29T02:20:16.089614+00:00 app[web.1]: self.stop()
2020-09-29T02:20:16.089656+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
2020-09-29T02:20:16.089962+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1)
2020-09-29T02:20:16.089968+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2020-09-29T02:20:16.090204+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2020-09-29T02:20:16.090208+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2020-09-29T02:20:16.090451+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2020-09-29T02:20:16.090483+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2020-09-29T02:20:16.206973+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-09-29T02:20:16.294069+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-09-29T02:20:16.296561+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-09-29T02:20:23.470291+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn locallibrary.wsgi --log-file -`
2020-09-29T02:20:25.798816+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-09-29 02:20:25 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-09-29T02:20:25.799429+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-09-29 02:20:25 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:6637 (4)
2020-09-29T02:20:25.799605+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-09-29 02:20:25 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-09-29T02:20:25.804203+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-09-29 02:20:25 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-09-29T02:20:25.810080+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-09-29 02:20:25 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-09-29T02:20:25.810081+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-09-29T02:20:25.810082+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-09-29T02:20:25.810082+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-09-29T02:20:25.810082+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-09-29T02:20:25.810083+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-09-29T02:20:25.810083+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-09-29T02:20:25.810083+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-09-29T02:20:25.810083+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-09-29T02:20:25.810084+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-09-29T02:20:25.810084+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-09-29T02:20:25.810084+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-09-29T02:20:25.810084+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-09-29T02:20:25.810085+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-09-29T02:20:25.810085+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-09-29T02:20:25.810085+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-09-29T02:20:25.810085+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2020-09-29T02:20:25.810086+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-09-29T02:20:25.810086+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-09-29T02:20:25.810086+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-09-29T02:20:25.810086+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-09-29T02:20:25.810087+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-09-29T02:20:25.810087+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-09-29T02:20:25.810087+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-09-29T02:20:25.810087+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-09-29T02:20:25.810091+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'locallibrary'
2020-09-29T02:20:25.810223+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-09-29 02:20:25 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-09-29T02:20:25.838998+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-09-29 02:20:25 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-09-29T02:20:25.839138+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-09-29 02:20:25 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2020-09-29T02:20:25.908531+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2020-09-29T02:20:25.947412+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-09-29T02:20:40.909874+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fathomless-crag-23485.herokuapp.com request_id=9ab17484-998a-4e94-a4ae-f61a2887c6f0 fwd="67.183.161.159" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-09-29T02:20:41.208778+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fathomless-crag-23485.herokuapp.com request_id=ffbf1655-8878-49e8-9603-5f40d76e7beb fwd="67.183.161.159" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'locallibrary'` means a module is missing.

Comment: a module missing in the requirements.txt file? or a module needed to be installed

Comment: Hard to say! You have not provided any code nor your project structure.

Comment: Can you post your Procfile and wsgi.py?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR : open your procfile and change `locallibrary` to your app name, ie the root folder of your django project.

I presume you are working from [Django's tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/).  The app in the tutorial is called `locallibrary`, so you simply need to change this module in your procfile to look for your app name.  Procfile should look like :
`web: gunicorn YOUR_APP_NAME.wsgi --log-file -`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `locallibrary` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.

then

```
git add .
git commit -m "some text"
git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when first deploying Django apps on Heroku.  My issue was a missing Procfile.  This thread was helpful for me - you will note the exact same error in the initial question on this thread.  Just scroll down to the last few lines and the errors will look very familiar.

[Django: Heroku Failing to launch, at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28271011/django-heroku-failing-to-launch-at-error-code-h10-desc-app-crashed/40172326)