# Heroku Build succeeded but "application error" {Django app}

Tags: python, django, heroku, web-deployment

heroku log:

```
2021-02-11T09:33:17.289297+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ivytasks'
2021-02-11T09:33:17.289983+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-11 09:33:17 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2021-02-11T09:33:17.306006+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-02-11T09:33:17.429342+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-11 09:33:17 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-02-11T09:33:17.429457+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-11 09:33:17 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2021-02-11T09:33:17.511921+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2021-02-11T09:33:17.647676+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-02-11T09:33:18.929260+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ivytasks.herokuapp.com request_id=1d65f0f2-d28b-4f75-a02b-3f55c4d2ae2a fwd="154.97.8.251" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-02-11T09:33:19.373547+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ivytasks.herokuapp.com request_id=36c5d48e-3181-4cf0-9f55-655dad447156 fwd="154.97.8.251" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

you can check the project repo link: [github.com/osamamhd/ivyTasks](https://github.com/osamamhd/ivyTasks/)

Comment: Don't know what's the problem but a small advice hide your `SECRET_KEY` in GitHub repo found a same error on stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28271011/django-heroku-failing-to-launch-at-error-code-h10-desc-app-crashed/40172326)

Answer (score 0):

First, Add your Heroku-generated url to `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in `settings.py`.

Then add `gunicorn` to `requirements.txt` to make sure heroku download the package for you

Finally add a file called `Procfile` in the root of your project (same path as `manage.py`) containing this:

`web: gunicorn ivytasks_project.wsgi --log-file -`

Then in you heroku dashboard in the overview tab scroll down to `Dyno Formation` and enable the worker if its OFF.

Answer (score 0):

If you Are Using any type of Virtual environment Or pipenv Make sure again everything is in the "Lock" file or included !
My Lock file was missing some stuff

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).